# How to optimize Minkowski dominated polynomials $ \lambda\left(x_1^{2 d}+\ldots+x_n^{2 d}\right)+q\left(x_1, \ldots, x_n\right) $?

Tags: polynomials

This question in about **GLOBAL** optimization of multivariable polynomials.

Given a multivariable polynomial $q\left(x_1, \ldots, x_n\right) $, one trick to find its global minimum is to construct an auxiliary polynomial $p_\lambda$ by adding a *dominating term* $$\lambda\left(x_1^{2 d}+\ldots+x_n^{2 d}\right)$$ and let $$\lambda\downarrow0$$ in the following auxiliary polynomial:

$$
p_\lambda\left(x_1, \ldots, x_n\right):=\lambda\left(x_1^{2 d}+\ldots+x_n^{2 d}\right)+q\left(x_1, \ldots, x_n\right).
$$

(The dominating term is related to the so called Minkowski $2d$-norm$
\left\|\left(x_1, \ldots, x_n\right)\right\|_{2 d}=\left(x_1^{2 d}+x_2^{2 d}+\ldots+x_n^{2 d}\right)^{1 /(2 d)}
$)
(references at the bottom):

The PROBLEM is when the researchers exemplify this method they JUST set $\lambda=1$ but don't explain this step. For example see the image below:

Please explain why it is not necessary to force the limit $\lambda\downarrow0$ (or in more complex words: why it is not necessary to use advanced theories like "simultaneous solutions of extremal eigenvalues of several parametric matrices").

[image]
[Algebraic polynomial system solving and applications](https://cris.maastrichtuniversity.nl/ws/portalfiles/portal/904972/guid-2f51c5f0-cae6-48cd-9be5-92074a7c7c6f-ASSET1.0.pdf)

[Global Minimization of a Multivariate Polynomial using Matrix Methods](https://d1wqtxts1xzle7.cloudfront.net/67107421/a_3A102466443254020210505-31714-2fgdav-libre.pdf?1620372686=&response-content-disposition=inline%3B+filename%3DGlobal_minimization_of_a_multivariate_po.pdf&Expires=1710362926&Signature=HxS7nXTK7qITNajHUR1U7QFe9UrxoFhHNPGVbclBtz98mAqtWYPN6lHvKDlOpZGyM6Cmbbl3qnyFxBnUeQXjphco3wKsGccS32h3fig-u6GeU-bAuMa9GklWN88avdAn2v0dXZsqQFdOSfT0huaw%7E8TmUg37DDLHjBwz6Ua8CFsGprpZngXtUfYci2%7EpmXwoems2EC9g8bgy3dCiv5QCIcf9J33BOjxxXrJE2t9pBoNFFPHT5wvD%7Eqh0Xa%7EIdfkft%7EzcA%7ER5eo2%7Ea6CexYAUbmLkxa7COyYrT651JPxZGgyyr9IH-tQhJ7LXMEsyWXAGY2xp79a591Y93Zz%7EpgYuDw__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLOHF5GGSLRBV4ZA)